# Splitting a Delimited String Variable in SAS into Individual Variables

Tags: arrays, sas

I'm hoping someone can help me out with this issue. I am trying to take a string variable which contains a series of delimited pick list responses. There can be no response, one response (e.g., 1234), or several responses (e.g., 1234;9876) in a single variable. Different options are always delimited by a semicolon (;). I'd like to split this single variable into multiple variables based on the delimiter.

For example, reasons=1234;9876 -> reason1=1234, reason2=9876

Traditionally I have done this the manual way using the scan function. The problem is I have up to (in this case) 10 pick list items concatenated in a single string.

```
data want;
set got;
   length reason1-reason10 $10;
     if reasons ne ' ' then reason1=scan(reasons, 1, ';');
     if reasons ne ' ' then reason2=scan(reasons, 2, ';');
     if reasons ne ' ' then reason3=scan(reasons, 3, ';');
 ...
 run;
```

and so on...

I feel like an array would greatly simplify this process. However, I am now just learning how to use arrays. Any advice on how to split this string variable with more efficient code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to solve this varies based on your size of dataset and complexity - how many possible variables might there be?

If there's a small, known-ahead number of variables, then your method is fine.  Arrays will help slightly:

```
data got;
  informat reasons $30.;
  input reasons $;
  datalines4;
123;456;789;101112
456;789;101112;131415
;;;;
run;



data want;
  set got;
  length reason1-reason10 $10;
  array reason(10) $;
  do _i = 1 to dim(reason);
    reason[_i] = scan(reasons,_i,';');
  end;
run;
```

You don't even have to check if it's missing, SCAN will behave fine with that.

If you're not sure what the number of variables might be (and don't want the 'maximum' if it is never reached), `PROC TRANSPOSE` is better.

First put a row out for each scanned value, all in one variable.  Then transpose it.

Adding an `id` variable to make this easier:

```
data got;
  informat reasons $30.;
  input id reasons $;
  datalines4;
1 123;456;789;101112
2 456;789;101112;131415
;;;;
run;

data got_pret;
  set got;
  do _i = 1 to countw(reasons,';');
    reason=scan(reasons,_i,';');
    output;
  end;
  keep reason id;
run;

proc transpose data=got_pret out=want prefix=reason;
  by id;
  var reason;
run;
```

That has the great advantage of not requiring to know how many there are ahead of time.  It is one more step though, so for a *huge* dataset it may be less preferred (though you can use a data step `view` to save some of this).

Comment: Thank you very much! Both of your solutions will be useful going forward. Have a great day!